# How to change animation fps in the Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to combine two animations on the same model, one I got from Internet comes as 30fps. Then I am trying to add a second animation on the same game object and I would like it would be also 30fps, but when creating the animation in the Editor, Unity set it as default to 60fps. I am not able to change that value in the Animator window and in the Inspector the value appears greyed out. I am using Unity 2020.3.29.

Is there any way to change this value in the Editor itself without coding?

Comment: You need to go to Debug Mode in the inespector, there you can update the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

In the Inspector, open the clip ( 60FPS appears greyed out as you said)

[image]

Go to the left menu and select **Debug** (by default you may have **Normal**).

[image]

Then you will have the option to edit the Sample Rate from 60 to 30, or the value you prefer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio's answer works. But another way to do that, is to change the whole game FPS using:

```
Application.TargetFrameRate = 30;
```